# jquery toggle "variable" div

Tags: jquery, variables, toggle

I have result page from DB,  on each row I have show/hide button that should show/hide container with $title....

I tried with jquery but it wont work :(

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="show_hide_button_<? echo $article_id_tmp; ?>"><a href="#">show/hide</a></div>
    <div class="show_hide_container_<? echo $article_id_tmp; ?>">
</div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
var div_id = '$article_id_tmp';

div_id_b+='.show_hide_button_'+ 'div_id';
div_id_c+='.show_hide_container_'+ 'div_id';

$(function(){
  $('div_id_b').click(function(){
     $('div_id_c').toggle();     
  });
});
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are variables, not strings, so you shouldn't be enclosing them within spaces:

```
var div_id = '$article_id_tmp';

div_id_b+='.show_hide_button_'+ 'div_id';
div_id_c+='.show_hide_container_'+ 'div_id';

$(function(){
  $(div_id_b).click(function(){
     $(div_id_c).toggle();     
  });
});
```

Furthermore, you need to `echo` the `$article_id_tmp` in the JS:

```
var div_id = '<?php echo $article_id_tmp ?>';

div_id_b+='.show_hide_button_'+ 'div_id';
div_id_c+='.show_hide_container_'+ 'div_id';

$(function(){
  $(div_id_b).click(function(){
     $(div_id_c).toggle();     
  });
});
```

Additionally, `classes` are usually used to group similar elements on a page; however you're assigning different classes to every element. For consistency, you might want to consider using an "id" instead of a class, or more preferably, something like the following:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="show_hide_button"><a href="#">show/hide</a></div>
   <div class="container">
   </div>
</div>

$('.show_hide_button').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.container').toggle();
});
```

You can of course, remove the `container` class, and just use `$(this).next().toggle()`

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript code needs to have the PHP variable correctly output, as you have already done in the HTML. So you need to change:

```
var div_id = '$article_id_tmp';
```

to

```
var div_id = '<?php echo $article_id_tmp; ?>';
```

This requires that the `<script>` be output *inline* as in your question. The JavaScript cannot exist in this form in a separate file.

**And** as @Matt has answered, the `div_id` is a variable, and should not be quoted when concatenating together when assigning to the `div_id_b` and `div_id_c` variables. The assignment should be:

```
var div_id_b = '.show_hide_button_' + div_id;
var div_id_c = '.show_hide_container_' + div_id;
```

**And** lastly the jQuery selectors do not require quoting, since they are variables already. The existing code will be looking for an *element* called `div_id_b` which does not exist.

The correct selectors should be `$(div_id_b).click(...)` and `$(div_id_c).toggle();`

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you would have to write

```
var div_id = '<?php echo $article_id_tmp; ?>';
```

instead of

```
var div_id = '$article_id_tmp';
```

So that you are actually feeding in the right string. Otherwise `div_id` will always be the `string '$article_id_tmp'`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to simplify you markup. Use some classes to mark the `show/hide` button and some classes to you `content` container. And the script will be very small and understandable:

```
$('.container .show_hide_button a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.show_hide_container').toggle();
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gYkKz/4/